# How do I open multiple files with the same extension

Tags: batch-file

I want to open every file that ends with .jar in my Downloads folder. My code doesn't work. What am I doing wrong and how do I achieve my end goal?

Code:

```
del /s /q "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\session.*"
cls
:choice
cls
set /P c=Open the file? [Y/N]
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :start
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :choice
goto :choice

:start
start "" "C:\Users\Home Computer\Downloads\????.jar"
del /s /q "C:\Windows\Prefetch\JAVA*.pf"
del /s /q "C:\Users\Home Computer\Recent\*.bat.lnk"
del /s /q "C:\Users\Home Computer\Recent\????.jar.*"
del /s /q "C:\Users\Home Computer\Recent\Downloads.lnk"
pause
```

Edit: I should also mention that the name of the .jar changes every time I re download it. I can't target it specifically by file name. The file name is always four characters.

Take a look at these two screenshots.
https://gyazo.com/579ebd940bcd74f3a3deeb05db7b337d

https://gyazo.com/ceaffd97bf1f1e81860036810b35fcd7

Comment: Weird; that should work. Is it starting _any_ of the jar files?

Comment: No. Take a look at this: https://gyazo.com/579ebd940bcd74f3a3deeb05db7b337d

Comment: Do the files show up in the output of `dir "C:\Users\Home Computer\Downloads"`?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the file has same number of characters everytime, then you can use ? for each character instead of *.
Say the filename is 3 characters long, then you can write the command as:

```
start "" "C:\Users\Home Computer\Downloads\???.jar"
```

Maybe you can take some references from the link given below:

https://www.howtogeek.com/111859/how-to-batch-rename-files-in-windows-4-ways-to-rename-multiple-files/

Comment: Weird. This happens with the *.jar and ????.jar - https://gyazo.com/ceaffd97bf1f1e81860036810b35fcd7

Comment: then maybe the IP of the target file is not static.

Comment: The IP of the target file? You mean where I got it from? The name is random every time.

Comment: Tty running the cmd with admin priviledges or run as administrator. Then type the same command again

Comment: And it isn't a cmd it's a batch file. Running the batch file as admin didn't help

Answer (score 0):

try

```
start "" "C:\Users\Home Computer\Downloads\*.jar"
```

or

```
java -jar "C:\Users\Home Computer\Downloads\*.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Where` command to identify the name of the downloaded file. *(Of course it will only identify it if you don't have more than one four character .jar file there)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
Del/S/Q "%AppData%\.minecraft\session.*" 2>Nul

:Pick
ClS
Choice /M "Open the file"
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo :EOF
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo Pick
If ErrorLevel 1 GoTo Start
GoTo :EOF

:Start
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where "%UserProfile%\Downloads":"????.jar"'
) Do (Set "FullName=%%~fA" & Set "Name=%%~nxA")
Start "" "%FullName%"
Del/Q "%SystemRoot%\Prefetch\JAVA*.pf" 2>Nul
Del/Q "%UserProfile%\Recent\%~nx0.lnk" 2>Nul
Del/Q "%UserProfile%\Recent\%Name%.lnk" 2>Nul
Del "%UserProfile%\Recent\Downloads.lnk" 2>Nul
Timeout -1
```

*You could even shorten it a little by deleting more than one of the shortcuts from the same delete line*.
The locations you've used for `recent` are effectively only links to the real location in modern Windows versions so you could replace `%UserProfile%\Recent` with `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`.